# Jquery (or css) in php to show div to logged in users only (wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Building a website on wordpress
Trying to make a couple of divs visible to logged in users only. I've set display:none in stylesheet and here is how i'm trying to make it visible to logged in users. Not working though...

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".single_add_to_cart_button").css('display','block');
$(".add_to_cart_button").css('display','block');
});
</script>
<? } ?>
```

If anyone can think of other ways- it will be greatly appreciated as well

Comment: Can you post the markup (HTML) of your div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `is_user_logged_in()` is actually working, I like to just output a class to the body. This class can then be used in numerous ways (both js and css).

Something like:

```
<body<?php echo (is_user_logged_in() ? ' class="logged-in"' : ''); ?>>
```

This will produce either

```
<body>
```

Or

```
<body class="logged-in">
```

And some css like this:

```
.single_add_to_cart_button {
    display: none;
}
.logged-in .single_add_to_cart_button {
    display: block;
}
```

For js, you can just check

```
if ($('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to forget having a hidden div for unauthenticated users - anyone could unhide this content if they want to, which in some cases could be quite bad depending on the rest of your system. It also means you have to run JavaScript to make things work as well as PHP.

What you should really do is simply check if the user is logged in with PHP and only output the div at all in that case.
Something like this:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>
<div class="blah...">
Content here
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to post the markup of your hidden divs though, and still want to do it how you're doing it, maybe we can find why it's not working.